# C++11: Does "auto" keyword retrieves cv-qualifier at all? I've contradictory sample

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, auto

I've got program like below:

```
struct A{ int i; };

int main()
{
    const int i = 0;
    auto ai = i;
    ai = 2; // OK

    const A buf[2];
    for(auto& a : buf)
    {
        a.i = 1; // error!
    }

    std::cout << buf[0].i << buf[1].i << std::endl;
}
```

The first `auto ai = i;` has no problem, seems `auto` doesn't retrieve c/v qualifier, as `ai` can be modified
But the for loop fails compilation as--error: assignment of member `A::i` in read-only object

I knew that `auto` doesn't retrieve `&` feature, 
my question is: does `auto` retrieve c/v qualifier like in my case?
My test program seems to give contradictory hints.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are copying `ai` here, not modifying it:

```
const int i = 0;
auto ai = i;
```

The code above is equivalent to:

```
const int i = 0;
int ai = i;
```

---

If you try to take a non-`const` reference, you will get a compile-time error:

```
const int i = 0;
auto& ai = i;
ai = 5; // Error: assignment of read-only reference 'ai'
```

As suggested by [Pau Guillamon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3531242/pau-guillamon), here's a snippet equivalent to the code above:

```
const int i = 0;
const int& ai = i;
ai = 5;
```

More details regarding the `auto` specifier [can be found on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).

Comment: For claryfing about the auto keyword I would also add that the last code snippet is equivalent to:
const int i = 0;
const int& ai = i;
ai = 5;
which will obviously result in the same compilation error.

Comment: @Hind Forsum: have you consider accepting this answer?